# Difference between BCH code in MATLAB and python

Tags: python, matlab, error-correction

I have to implement a BCH error-correcting code. I have found some codes in Python [BCH library Python](https://github.com/jkent/python-bchlib) and MATLAB [BCH encoder in MATLAB](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/bchenc.html). However, codes have different performance, `BCH(127,70)` in Python can correct up to 70 bitflips in a block size of 127. However, the MATLAB code can correct up to only 15 bits in 127 bits in `BCH(127,15)`.

Why do these implementation perform differently?

Python Code

```py
import bchlib
import hashlib
import os
import random

# create a bch object
BCH_POLYNOMIAL = 8219
BCH_BITS = 72
bch = bchlib.BCH(BCH_POLYNOMIAL, BCH_BITS)

# random data
data = bytearray(os.urandom(127))

# encode and make a "packet"
ecc = bch.encode(data)
packet = data + ecc
# print length of ecc, data, and packet
print('data size: %d' % (len(data)))
print('ecc size: %d' % (len(ecc)))
print('packet size: %d' % (len(packet)))

# print hash of packet
sha1_initial = hashlib.sha1(packet)
print('sha1: %s' % (sha1_initial.hexdigest(),))

def bitflip(packet):
    byte_num = random.randint(0, len(packet) - 1)
    bit_num = random.randint(0, 7)
    packet[byte_num] ^= (1 << bit_num)

# make BCH_BITS errors
for _ in range(BCH_BITS):
    bitflip(packet)

# print hash of packet
sha1_corrupt = hashlib.sha1(packet)
print('sha1: %s' % (sha1_corrupt.hexdigest(),))

# de-packetize
data, ecc = packet[:-bch.ecc_bytes], packet[-bch.ecc_bytes:]

# correct
bitflips = bch.decode_inplace(data, ecc)
print('bitflips: %d' % (bitflips))

# packetize
packet = data + ecc

# print hash of packet
sha1_corrected = hashlib.sha1(packet)
print('sha1: %s' % (sha1_corrected.hexdigest(),))

if sha1_initial.digest() == sha1_corrected.digest():
    print('Corrected!')
else:
    print('Failed')
```

This outputs

```py
data size: 127
ecc size: 117
packet size: 244
sha1: 4ee71f947fc5d561b211a551c87fdef18a83404b
sha1: a072664312114fe59f5aa262bed853e35d70d349
bitflips: 72
sha1: 4ee71f947fc5d561b211a551c87fdef18a83404b
Corrected!
```

MATLAB code

```matlab
%% bch params
M = 7;
n = 2^M-1;   % Codeword length
k = 15;       % Message length
nwords = 2; % Number of words to encode
% create a msg
msgTx = gf(randi([0 1],nwords,k));
%disp(msgTx)
%Find the error-correction capability.
t = bchnumerr(n,k)
% Encode the message.
enc = bchenc(msgTx,n,k);
%Corrupt up to t bits in each codeword.
noisycode = enc + randerr(nwords,n,1:t);
%Decode the noisy code.
msgRx = bchdec(noisycode,n,k);
% Validate that the message was properly decoded.
isequal(msgTx,msgRx)
```

which outputs:

```matlab
t = 27
ans = logical 1
```

Increasing `k>15` in MATLAB code gives following error:

```
Error using bchnumerr (line 72)
The values for N and K do not produce a valid narrow-sense BCH code.

Error in bchTest (line 10)
t = bchnumerr(n,k)
```

Comment: @Machavity I have added the code in the post. You can check it now.

Comment: @Machavity, I will change the question as you suggested removing the "which one is better to use" sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered this question today (24 January 2021) as I searched for other information about BCH codes.

See [Appendix A: *Code Generators for BCH Codes*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm:978-1-4899-2174-1/1.pdf) (pdf) of [*Error-Correction Coding for Digital Communications*](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780306406157?utm_campaign=3_pier05_buy_print&utm_content=en_08082017&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=google_books) by George C. Clark and J. Bibb Cain:

- For ***n* = 127** and ***k* = 15**, ***t* = 27** is the number of errors that can be corrected.
- For ***n* = 127**, the next option with larger *k* is ***k* = 22** and ***t* = 23**.

Your use of the Python library is confusing. For standard usage of BCH codes, the length of a **codeword** is equal to 2<sup>*m*</sup> - 1 for some positive integer *m*. The codeword in your example is not of this form.

I have not used that Python library, so I cannot write with certainty. If `ecc` is of length 127, then I *suspect* that it is a codeword. Concatenating `ecc` and `data` yields a packet that has a copy of the original message data as well as a copy of the codeword. This is not how BCH codes are used. When you have the codeword, you don't need to send it *and* a separate copy of the original message.

---

If you do read the reference linked above, be aware of the notation used to describe the polynomials. For the ***n* = 127** table, the polynomial *g*<sub>1</sub>(*x*) is denoted by **211**, which is octal notation. The nonzero bits in the binary expressions indicate the nonzero coefficients of the polynomial.

- octal: 211
- binary: 010  001  001
- polynomial: *x*<sup>7</sup> + *x*<sup>3</sup> + 1

The polynomial *g*<sub>2</sub>(*x*) is equal to *g*<sub>1</sub>(*x*) multiplied by another polynomial:

- octal: 217
- binary: 010  001  111
- polynomial: *x*<sup>7</sup> + *x*<sup>3</sup> + *x*<sup>2</sup> + *x* + 1

This means that

*g*<sub>2</sub>(*x*) = (*x*<sup>7</sup> + *x*<sup>3</sup> + 1)(*x*<sup>7</sup> + *x*<sup>3</sup> + *x*<sup>2</sup> + *x* + 1)

Each *g*<sub>*t*+1</sub>(*x*) is equal to *g*<sub>*t*</sub>(*x*) multiplied by another polynomial.